# Powershell: Is it possible to have a service depend on remote services

Tags: powershell, service, dependencies

I'm using Win32 Service object and there's Change which could be used to set Dependencies. Is it possible to set the service to depend on services running on a different machine? Currently, all the services run on the same machine but it's possible to run them each on a separate machine.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing like that exists today, AFAIK. It is a good ask. Check this MS connect item: http://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/293384/remote-machine-service-dependency

That said, you can create a script or another service to poll remote machines for dependent service startup and then start the local service.